# Why is my httpServletRequest coming back NULL?

Tags: java, jsp, web

Why is my httpServletRequest coming back null?

```
<form action="updateUserData" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<%=user_email%>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="usermail">Email</label></td>
        <td><%=user_email%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" required> <br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><label for="user_name">Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user_name" value="<%=user_name%>" required> <br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><label for="user_name">Total Wins</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total_wins" value=<%=total_wins%> required> <br></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Here is my servlet :

Servlet :

```
resp.getWriter().println(" email from jsp : " + req.getAttribute("email"));
resp.getWriter().println(" password from jsp : " + req.getAttribute("password"));
resp.getWriter().println(" user's name from jsp : " + req.getAttribute("user_name"));
resp.getWriter().println(" total score from jsp : " + req.getAttribute("total_wins"));
```

When I hit sumbit all of the out put says null.  I cannot figure out why.  Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use getParameter not getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

You should use `req.getParameter` instead of `req.getAttribute` and take a look on the javadoc of these 2 methods [getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Because attributes are used to pass data between various layers of servlet processing (servlets, filters, jsp etc). Client data is called parameter.